# Is there anything like pkg-config for Java?

Tags: java, classpath, pkg-config

I have a project where our CLASSPATH is getting out of hand.  We have jars that depend on other jars, which in turn depend on even more jars, as well as a large collection of third-party jars.  So each time we use one of these jars we need to construct a rather large CLASSPATH, and if downstream dependencies change it is no longer in sync.

One thought is to maybe write a tool a little like pkg-config to help with all of this.  I did some searching and didn't find anything.  Are there any tools like this that I've missed or do people have alternate solutions?

No, I don't want to use Maven.  We already have a different build system in place.

Comment: Have you looked at Maven? http://maven.apache.org/ - I'm not a big fan myself, but it's meant to help with this sort of thing...

Comment: Or Ivy, which is Maven dependency management without the fuss.

Comment: Your jars can each have their own classpath stuff in the manifest.

Comment: Queue up the religious war.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't already using a build tool, I recommend starting with [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). The main thing that turns people off Maven is that it has a standard project structure. Personally, I think that's a good thing.

If you want to be a little more free-form with your projects, there are the [Maven Ant Tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html) for [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/). I much prefer these to Ivy, but part of that is because I'm used to the Maven artifact naming conventions.

In either case (or if you use Ivy), look into a repository manager. [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) is written by the people who maintain Maven, and I find it easier to use than [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/), which is another widely used system. One benefit for Artifactory is that they provide hosting (for a fee).

Comment: I agree strongly with the maven recommendation here. There is a bit of a learning curve but its well worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use maven with an IDE plugin like m2eclipse. All you have to do is type the class in your code and it will help you search for and bring in the right packages with their dependancies. It will also automatically configure the classpath for you. Here is a quick tutorial http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/03/adding-dependencies-using-m2eclipse/